# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'newsletterAPI.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: python, django

project name: newsletterAPI
app name: newsletterApp

after running `python3 manage.py runserver` getting the above error

Comment: check your middlewares

Comment: missed a comma(,)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a missing middlewares like @ALireza said above. In my case it was the whitenoise.

so do

> pip install whitenoise